# Tempt or entice vs tantalize

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Based on dictionary definitions, all of the following bold verbs should work properly in my self-made sentence. Which one of the following words doesn't sound idiomatic in English and why? (For me they all seem to be normal, but I need to know which one would be preferred by a native especially in AE). Meanwhile, I have no idea if one of them in this specific sense would sound too formal or unnatural:

> - The jewelry in the shops window [tempted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tempt) her.
> - The jewelry in the shops window [enticed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/entice) her.
> - The jewelry in the shops window [tantalized](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tantalize) her.

Comment: BTW-comment, I think you shouldn't use "both" for three things.

Comment: Yea. ;) Actually, they were two first, but I added one more choice. Thank you Cardinal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about writing advice are off topic.

Comment: **shop window** or **shop windows**.

Comment: @AlanCarmack how did you get to this matter that asking this question I am going to get an advice about writing style? Could you please make it clear for me and some other people who may have the same question? I am eagerly waiting for your response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three sentences are OK if you correct the **shops window** bit. When you have a compound noun like shop window, only the last word is pluralized- **shop windows**.

If you read the definition of **tantalize**, you will see that it is different. In addition to attracting one's attention, it also "is made difficult or impossible to obtain".

I can be **tempted** or **enticed** by a cake in the shop window, I know that it is not good for me, but if I want to I can go in and buy it.

I can be **tantalized** by a diamond necklace in the shop window... it attracts me but I know that it is unattainable because I cannot afford it.

Comment: Thank you very much JavaLatte. It was really helpful. :)

Answer (score 3):

"Tempting" is associated with vice, something very desireable but forbidden. For instance, in the story of Genesis, Eve was tempted to eat the apple.   Often this metaphorical "forbidden fruit" is even more desireable because of the thrill of breaking the rules.

"Tantalized" is associated with hunger, and originates from a Greek myth about a man tormented by food and drink forever just out of reach.  The smell of a fine restaurant might be tantalizing to a hungry man, or a fat wallet might be tantalizing to a thief.

"Enticed" is usually playing to someone's sense of greed. You might entice customers with a sale, or entice a strange dog with a treat.  Enticed also implies something that is available for a reasonable price, as opposed to a forbidden temptation or an unreachable tantalization.

The tricky thing here is that all three of these could work for your jewelry example, depending upon how she felt about the purchase.  All three of these words imply that there is a reason why she should not pursue the jewelry, but she is considering pursuing it anyway.  Choosing the appropriate word tells us more about her motivations.

I would choose "tempting" if she is held back by her morals, "tantalizing" if it is beyond her reach (perhaps requiring her to leave her comfort zone and take a risk), or "enticed" if she is simply weighing the budget.